# Objective-C - Accessing property from different class

Tags: ios, objective-c

So in my `VC1.h` I got:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *monthly;
```

This is connected to a button on a view which is connected to the `VC1` class.
How do I access this button's `.enabled` property in a different class?

Edit:

I have a class connected to a tableview. When selecting a specific row in the tableview I want to disable a button in my mainclass. All I need to know is how to get the current state of the button and disable it in another class.

**IBaction from button:**

```
- (IBAction)monthly:(id)sender {
[monthly setSelected:YES];
yearly.enabled = YES;

if([monthly isSelected])
{
    NSLog(@"monthly ON");
    [yearly setSelected:NO];
    monthly.enabled = NO;

    _dateSpecifiedYearButton.hidden = TRUE;
    _dateSpecifiedYearButton.enabled = NO;
    _dateSpecifiedButton.hidden = FALSE;
    _dateSpecifiedButton.enabled = YES;
}

}
```

**Tableview.m :**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[popoverSpending dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(spendingButtonText:)]) {
    [self.delegate spendingButtonText:cell.textLabel.text];
}

if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    NSLog(@"2");

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    if (vc.monthly.enabled)
    {
        vc.monthly.enabled = NO;
        vc.yearly.enabled = NO;           
    }
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So above are the parts of the code that could matter for this question.

Comment: `(instance of VC1).monthly.enabled`? There is no magic behind accessing properties.

Comment: how VC1 and VC2 are related?

Comment: @mAu Well I cant seem to figure it out. Your suggestion is not helping me.

Comment: Your problem is how you're instantiating vc -- just doing an alloc init creates a different instance from the one you have on screen. You need to say how you are going from ViewController to the controller with the table view. How these 2 controllers relate to each other is important to answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
VC1 *vc = [[VC1 alloc] init];//Allocate VC1 in appDelegate, if you allocate VC1 in VC2, then it allocates new instance. 


AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if (app.vc.monthly.enabled)//chk button state
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. It seems I can acces the properties this way, but my button state is not changing however. ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        if (vc.monthly.enabled)
        {
            vc.monthly.enabled = NO;
            vc.yearly.enabled = NO;
        }

Comment: @Tarayaa chk my updated answer.

Comment: I need to acces the enabled status in a didSelectRow method specifically on a class. So the enabled check cant be in the appDelegate. Where in my appdelegate should I allocate it?

Comment: In appDelegate just allocate VC1. chk button state by creating appdelegate instance in table didSelectRow method.

Comment: No thats not going to do what I want. I want to change the state in a specific method in a specific class.

Comment: then you should express what your goal is, explicitly

Comment: @Tarayaa my answer is as per your question.

Comment: It is still vague to me. Maybe you should share some partial code related with your class and the tableView associated with it.

Comment: @Bartu dont really understand why cause im just trying to access a current property in another class but alright.

Comment: @Bartu see second edit

Comment: @Tarayaa create appdelegate instance like AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; & then access if (app.viewController.monthly) may solve your problem.

Comment: @Girish I never worked with AppDelegate before so I have no clue where to put what code.

Comment: replace following line ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init]; with AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: @Tarayaa please consider a good lecture for learning iOS development, as your questions are very basic and should be explained in every beginner iOS book.

Comment: @mAu That might be, and im planning on reading a few books this summer, but that's not something I can do right now im afraid.

Comment: @Tarayaa your problem solved or not???

Comment: @girish no it is not, your code did not work.

Comment: @Tarayaa what you have tried?