# Objective-c / xcode - Access button state in different class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

So I tried this in many different ways but I can't get it to work. Im trying to change the state of a UIbutton in a different class.

**class1.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *monthly;
```

**class2.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    vc.monthly.enabled = NO;
}
```

Whatever I try and where ever I put the code, the button state is not changing. When I log the state in class2.m:

```
NSLog(vc.monthly.enabled ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

It always returns No, even if I just stated it as `YES` in my class2.m. Long story short: My button property is not updating from a different class. Please tell me if you need to see any more code and i'll update asap.

Comment: Check the connection of IBOutlet. Do you find proper object for UIButton in your code?

Comment: You are not accessing your button. You are initiating a new view controller and accessing it's button.

Comment: @Apurv what do you mean..? I dont think their is anything wrong with the outlet cause its working in the main class.

Comment: @Desdenova So how would I acces the original button from a different class? I also tried using a global variable set as the button state but that didnt work either.

Comment: When you are enabling the button, it is not instantiated if you have added it through XIB. Set a flag and using that flag set the button status from viewDidLoad:

Comment: What is the relation b/w class1 and class2? means the transformation class1->class2 or class2->class1.. Also how you are doing?

Comment: Don't do it. Make `IBOutlet`s private by declaring them in a class extension in the .m file. Then declare a public instance in the class to make the change. Then you have one controller of the view item.

Comment: @Tarayaa your previous question is same like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712692/objective-c-accessing-property-from-different-class

Comment: How are classes 1 and 2 related?

Comment: In class 2 I added @class class1;. If thats what you mean.

Comment: This is very basic thing in iOS unfortunately you dont know that.. Its better to post the full code both class1 and class2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think problem is with class instance. the following line create new instance

> ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

that's why your button state is not changing you have to get reference of your previously created intstace no need to create new instance.

for this you can use AppDelegate file to declare property of class1.

see following code

AppDelegate.h

> @Property(nonatomic, ratain) ViewController *vc;

AppDelegate.m

> @synthesize vc;

now alloc & initialize vc whenever you need it like following.

> AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication
>   sharedApplication] delegate]; 
>   appDelegate.vc=[[ViewController alloc] init];

also don't forgot to import AppDelegate.h file where you write above code.

now using appDelegate.vc you can use all property of View Controller in all classes of you project.

Comment: I did all the steps you suggested and in my class2.m I added: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"SPENDINGVIEW REACHED");
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; appDelegate.vc=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    appDelegate.vc.monthly.enabled = NO;}. The NSLog is working but my button state is still not changing..

Comment: @Tarayaa have you included AppDelegate.h in class2.m?

Comment: Yes I did, not getting any errors but the state is not changing.

Comment: @Tarayaa make sure ViewController's instace declared only once in whole project

Comment: @P R J This gave me a clue in the good direction, I had: @property(nonatomic, assign) ViewController *delegate;
In my class. I removed the entire AppDelegate line and just added: _delegate.monthly.enabled = NO; and it worked. Can you explain why maybe?

Comment: @Tarayaa you have used @property(nonatomic, assign) while assign used for primitive types like BOOL,Int etc that's why it's not working try retain instead of assign it should work as I think because ViewContriller is a class so retain should be used

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are creating new instance each time when you are going to check the button state. But the button state is for the button which you have created in `class1.h`. So you have need that you should create button in `Appdelegate` class and fetch the instance from `Appdelegate` in the class where you are checking the status of button and check the status of button. I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Access the button using the object of the `ViewController` class that is already in the stack. No need to creat a new object like `ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];`. When you are doing this it creates a new object so you are not getting the write thing.